# Swift, after adding chromecast mini controller shouldautorotate not called

Tags: ios, swift, chromecast

I am making a video app in swift, and normally the app is in portrait mode, but when te user enters the player view he can rotate the device, i control this with shouldAutorotate, when i don't want the app to rotate i return false and vice versa.

I can't uncheck the device orientation flags, because i need the app to rotate.

The problem is when i add the chromcast's mini controller i have to set it up like this:

```
let appStoryBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let tmpNavigationController = appStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigationMain")

let castContainerVC: GCKUICastContainerViewController = GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().createCastContainerController(for: tmpNavigationController)

castContainerVC.miniMediaControlsItemEnabled = true

self.window?.rootViewController = castContainerVC
```

but as soon as i set rootViewController = castContainerVc my app stops calling the shouldAutorotate method and the app rotates freely everywhere, any workaround?

Comment: Did you found a solution? I have the same problem...

Comment: Any solutions? Same problem as well

Answer (score 2):

What you can do to manage the rotation state when **GCKUICastContainerViewController** is the **rootViewController** is:

> extending **GCKUICastContainerViewController** and override there what you need

**Swift 2.x**

```
extension GCKUICastContainerViewController{

override public func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    //Do what ever you need here
    return true
}

override public func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    //Do what ever you need here
    return .All
}

override public func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {
    //Do what ever you need here
    return .All
}}
```

**Swift 3.x**

```
extension GCKUICastContainerViewController{

override open var shouldAutorotate:Bool {
    //Do what ever you need here
    return true
}

override open var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    //Do what ever you need here
    return .all
}

override open var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation:UIInterfaceOrientation {
    //Do what ever you need here
    return .all
}}
```